# Is there a way to make the following method available to all the classes?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have a method `pdfviewer(...)` written in class `In_cs_3_s1`, which basically takes the file path, file name and URL as arguments. It first checks whether the file exists in the specified path, if it does then it invokes the pdf viewer. Else it downloads the file from the URL specified: to do this it invokes the DOWNLOAD MANAGER.I want to invoke this `method(pdfviewer)` from a lot of places.

Here's my code:

```
public void pdfviewer(String branch,String sem,String folder,String fname,String url,Context a)
{
     File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                +File.separator+"name"+File.separator+branch+File.separator+sem+File.separator+folder,fname);        

        if(file.exists())
        {

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                try 
                {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
                {
                     Toast.makeText( this, "NO pdf viewer found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
        else
        {   
                file_download(url,branch,sem,folder,fname);
                Toast.makeText( this, "Downloading.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}


public void file_download(String uRl,String branch,String sem,String folder,String fname) {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            +File.separator+"name"+File.separator+branch+File.separator
            +sem+File.separator+folder);

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/name"+File.separator+branch+File.separator
                    +sem+File.separator+folder,fname);

    mgr.enqueue(request);

}
```

i  want to invoke this method from the onclicklistener of a button. am a novice so please go easy.

Comment: you can't create a new instance of an Activity and just use it. New instances can be only created by Android system. Please read the very basics about android before starting programming, otherwise you will have hundreds of problems like this.

Comment: thank you! so if i put in the method in a different class that doesnt extends Activity , then it should work right?

Comment: okay i get it !! am a novice, its not wrong to commit mistakes.is there any way to make that method available to all the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global variable for the object:(outside onCreate Method) In first code

In_cs_3_s1 pobj;

The problem is inside onClick, it is not able to find pobj object;

Comment: Well, first of all its plain wrong to instantiate an Activity. (2) I think the code is independent of activity life-cycle. So create another Class and put these methods in that class and then call the function in onClick method. If at all you need the context of activity pass the activity context as function parameter. Hope this helps